# Annotation to modify a request parameter

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

How to modify a request parameter (`@RequestParam String bar`) before entering in the controller ?

Ideally I'd like to create an annotation :

```java
@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "foo")
public ResponseEntity<String> getBar(@RequestParam @Sanitize("bar") String bar) {

    // bar is sanitized

    /** method body *//
}
```

According [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715579/custom-spring-annotation-for-request-parameters), I tried to create the interface `Sanitize`:

```java
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Sanitize {
    String value();
}
```

And a resolver `SanitizeResolver`

```java
public class SanitizeResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Sanitize.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        Sanitize attr = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(Sanitize.class);
        return MyUtils.sanitize(webRequest.getParameter(attr.value()));
    }
}
```

And to add the resolver to my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`'s resolver:

```java
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new SanitizeResolver());
}
```

The resolver is well added but never called.

I'm using [Spring 4.2.6.RELEASE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).
Do I miss something, and if can't work, is there a better solution ?

Comment: At the moment, the resolver for `@RequestParam` is getting chosen _before_ your custom resolver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So currently there is no way to achieve that I guess ?

Comment: Get rid of `@RequestParam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove `@RequestParam`, thanks Sotirios Delimanolis !